# How to solve "Incompatible extents" error in exact_extract

Tags: r, raster, spatial, weighted-average

I am using the `exact_extract` function in R to get a regional weighted mean of a raster. I have a raster of population (`r_pop`) a raster of air pollution (`emis_pm`) some poligons in `sf` (`nuts_sf`). `emis_pm` is a raster that is created from a .txt file.

Both rasters have the same extent, resolution and CRS (see code below) but the `exact_extract` function gets the error `Incompatible extents.`.

Code:

```
r_pop
emis_pm
extent(nuts_sf)

emis_regions_w = exact_extract(x = emis_pm, 
                               nuts_sf,
                               fun = "weighted_mean",
                               weights = r_pop)
```

Result

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3500, 6300, 22050000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : -18, 45, 33, 68  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : reproj_merged_pop 
values     : 0, 58558.26  (min, max)

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3500, 6300, 22050000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : -18, 45, 33, 68  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2022-10-06_094124_28972_73881.grd 
names      : emission.1999..tons. 
values     : 1.36101e-07, 10865.3  (min, max)

class      : Extent 
xmin       : -18 
xmax       : 44.82037 
ymin       : 35.46326 
ymax       : 71.18416 

Error in CPP_stats(x, weights, wkb, default_value, default_weight, coverage_area, : 
Incompatible extents.
```

Full traceback:

```
10.
stop(structure(list(message = "Incompatible extents.", call = CPP_stats(x, 
weights, wkb, default_value, default_weight, coverage_area, 
area_method, fun, max_cells_in_memory, grid_compat_tol, quantiles), 
cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", ...
9.
CPP_stats(x, weights, wkb, default_value, default_weight, coverage_area, 
area_method, fun, max_cells_in_memory, grid_compat_tol, quantiles)
8.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
7.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
6.
sapply(sf::st_as_binary(geoms, EWKB = TRUE), function(wkb) {
ret <- CPP_stats(x, weights, wkb, default_value, default_weight, 
coverage_area, area_method, fun, max_cells_in_memory, 
grid_compat_tol, quantiles) ...
5.
tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4.
tryCatch({
x <- .startReading(x)
weights <- .startReading(weights)
if (is.character(fun)) { ...
3.
.local(x, y, ...)
2.
exact_extract(x = emis_pm, nuts_sf, fun = "weighted_mean", weights = agg_r_pop)
1.
exact_extract(x = emis_pm, nuts_sf, fun = "weighted_mean", weights = agg_r_pop)
```

Comment: Last minute note: 

The issue can be avoided if `emis_pm` is not modified with `emis_pm = emis_pm |>
  disaggregate(fact = 10) |>  crop(extent(r_pop))` but with `emis_pm = resample(emis_pm, r_pop, method = "bilinear")`

Comment: Thanks. I also had the same issue and I ended up doing the bilinear sampling as well